# MS CRM 2011 Fetch XML Filter Expressions

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I have a fetch xml query and I would like to filter records with a date & **time** field.

I use the expression **on or before** but this seems to filter only date (*without time*).

```
FetchXml= ...
'<filter type="and">'+
'<filter type="or">'+
    '<condition attribute="scheduledend" value="'+ currentdate +'" operator="on-or-before"/>'+
    '<condition attribute="scheduledend" operator="null"/>'+
'</filter>'+
'</filter>'+
```

Comment: I would play with the Advanced Find feature until I found a compatible query, then I would export this as XML ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can build the date and affect 0 to the time part. It's that you want?

```js
var date = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdon").getValue();
var d = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I would like to check time of my date. 
For example, If current date time is 14/03/2013 17:20 and my field date time is 14/03/2013 18:00 then my query should cut out the record.